# React JS pass object to an action

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form with validation on it and after it is creates the object "fields". How can I now pass this object to the action "createPost"? I'm guessing I need to do something with "props"? Or I'm guessing it might be something to do with the dispatcher line?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from '../components/header';
import Formous from 'formous';
import { createPost } from '../actions/index';

class ErrorText extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div style={{ color: '#f00' }}>
      {this.props.errorText}
    </div>
  }
}

class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // Set default form values (might be appropriate in a different method
    this.props.setDefaultValues({
      age: 33,
      name: 'Sir Andrew',
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(formStatus, fields) {
    if (!formStatus.touched) {
      alert('Please fill out the form.');
      return;
    }

    if (!formStatus.valid) {
      alert('Please address the errors in the form.');
      return;
    }

    // All good! Do something with fields.name.value and fields.age.value
    console.log(formStatus, fields);
  }

  render() {
    const {
      fields: { age, name },
      formSubmit,
    } = this.props;

    return <div>
    <Header />
      <form onSubmit={formSubmit(this.handleSubmit)}>
        <div>
          <input
            placeholder="Name"
            type="text"
            value={name.value}
            { ...name.events }
          />
          <ErrorText { ...name.failProps } />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input
            placeholder="Age"
            type="text"
            value={age.value}
            { ...age.events }
          />
          <ErrorText { ...age.failProps } />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  }
}

const formousOptions = {
  fields: {
    name: {
      tests: [
        {
          critical: true,
          failProps: {
            errorText: 'Name is required.',
          },
          test(value) {
            return value !== '';
          },
        }
      ],
    },

    age: {
      tests: [
        {
          critical: true,
          failProps: {
            errorText: 'Age should be a number.',
          },
          test(value) {
            return /^\d*$/.test(value);
          },
        },
        {
          critical: false,
          failProps: {
            errorText: 'Are you sure you\'re that old? :o',
          },
          test(value) {
            return +value < 120;
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
};

export default Formous(formousOptions)(MyComponent)
```

Comment: try dispatch(createPost(fields)) . I suggest you to use react-redux.

Comment: Can we see your actions/index file?

Comment: @Tugrul I've tried that, but now says "dispatch is not defined"

Comment: @HusseinAlkaf the actions file is fine, I just can't work out the line used to post to it.

Comment: What library are you using for your data? Redux, Flux etc

Comment: @HusseinAlkaf Redux :)

Comment: Try and inject your actionCreators before Formous. 
`connect(null, createPost)(Formous(formousOptions)(MyComponent))`. Do you have a parent component that is connected to the store? Here is a tutorial on this: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md

Comment: Use "redux-form"  instead of doing by your own, or if you still want to use then as mentioned by @tugrul use dispatch(createPost(fields))

Answer (score 0):

Dispatch the redux actions via props.

```
this.props.onMySubmit({
  name: fields.name.value,
  age: fields.age.value
});
```

redux-react action connectors (onMySubmit) will dispatch the action (action type and arguments) to the store. This is handled by the reducers to modify the state of the store.